# Validation in javascript is not working as it should

Tags: javascript, validation, email-validation

I have been trying to solve the problem that I am having with this email validation in JavaScript, but all the code I have tried was having the same problem. When I used the developer tool in google chrome I didn't see any error message, so I don't understand why is this happening. I want to show the error message if an email is not valid.

What am I missing?

link full code - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/cq1g5dyt/14/

Thanks.

```js
function checkEmail(validate) {
    let re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    let email = validate.userName.value;
    if (email === re)
        return true;
    else {
        error.setAttribute("class", "error");
        error.innerHTML = ("Email is not correct. Please retype.");
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JavaScript</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
 <section>
  <h1></h1>
  <ul>
   
  </ul>
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <p>* = Required Field</p>
  <div id="formcontainer">
   <form id="registerDetails" action="lmanha01_fma_t3confirm.html">
    <div>
     <label for="username">* Userame:</label>
     <input type="text" id="userName" required>
     <!--pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"-->
     <!--check that the user has in fact typed in an email address-->
     <div id="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="password">* Password (must be 8 characters exactly and include one Uppercase, one
      lowercase and
      one number):</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,8}$"
      required>
     <input type="checkbox" id="showpasswords" onclick="Toggle()">
     <!--This creates a toggle effect-->
     <label id="showpasswordslabel" for="showpasswords">Show passwords</label>
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="retypedpassword">* Retype your password:</label>
     <input type="password" id="retypedpassword">
     <span id="passwordmatcherror"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <button type="submit" id="registerButton">Register</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </section>
 <!--moved to the bottom to load the page faster-->
 <script src="scripts/exemple.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your form does not have an email field for the user to enter their data into. Also, why not just use `<input type="email">` and no script whatsoever?

Comment: Also, heading elements (`<h1>...<h6>`) are semantic elements and meant to denote the beginning of a section or sub-section. Don't use them because of the built-in styling that browsers provide for them.

Comment: `re` is a RegExp object. `email` is a string. You can't just compare a string against a regular expression. To do that, you would use the [`.test()` method of the regular expression object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)..

Comment: `.innerHTML` is used when a string containing HTML is being set and needs to be parsed. Don't use it when the string doesn't contain any HTML as there are security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead. Additionally, you don't put parenthesis around a string when it's being set.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **test()** method of regex to return true or false if input value matches the email pattern.

```
if (re.test(email)){
     //logic when it is valid
}       
else{
      //logic when it is invalid
}
```

```js
const email = document.getElementById('email');
function validate(){
   const regex=/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
  return regex.test(email.value) ?console.log("Valid"):console.log("Invalid");
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" />
<button onclick="validate()">
Validate
</button>
```